# create csv file in php that puts each row on a new line

Tags: php, csv, fwrite

I am using the fwrite() function in PHP to create a csv file. It connects to a database and retrieves two columns from a table. I can get this to work, however it only writes the first row. For example..

`+------+-----+--+--+--+
| John | Doe |  |  |  |
+------+-----+--+--+--+
|      |     |  |  |  |
+------+-----+--+--+--+
|      |     |  |  |  |
+------+-----+--+--+--+`

How do i get it to go onto the next line and write the next row, and keep on writing how ever many rows there are in the table. For example..

`+---------+-----+--+--+--+
| John    | Doe |  |  |  |
+---------+-----+--+--+--+
| Jane    | Doe |  |  |  |
+---------+-----+--+--+--+
| Richard | Doe |  |  |  |
+---------+-----+--+--+--+
|         |     |  |  |  |
+---------+-----+--+--+--+`

Here is my PHP code

```
fwrite($file, ucfirst($row['name']) . ', ' . ucfirst($row['visiting']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fputcsv` instead - it will take care of the formatting for you!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

```
fputcsv( $file, array( ucfirst($row['name']), ucfirst($row['visiting']) ) );
```